# autohotkey for opening chrome without bringing slack window to front

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey, slack

Hi I just learned that the Windows Application for Slack uses Chrome. I am not talking about using Slack in Chrome but the Windows Application.

In the past the following script worked for me to bring Chrome browser to front or if the Chrome application wasn't yet started, start it.

```
if WinExist("ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1")
{   
    WinActivate  ; Automatically uses the window found above.

}
else
{
    Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"       
}
```

Unfortunately as the Slack Window has the same `ahk_class` now, my script brings the Slack window to front. Therefore i tried to optimize my script like the following:

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2
DetectHiddenText 
On

if WinExist("ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1","Google Chrome")
{   
    WinActivate  ; Automatically uses the window found above.

}
else
{
    if WinExist("ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1") {
        WinActivate
        WinGetTitle, Title, A
        MsgBox, The active window is "%Title%".
    } else {    
        Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it does not work.  The line `if WinExist("ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1","Google Chrome")` still does NOT match the Google Chrome Browser Window although the line "MsgBox" shows me title which contains the string "- Google Chrome"

Can you please help?

Comment: Try `If WinExist("- Google Chrome ahk_exe chrome.exe")`

Comment: It still brings up the slack windows ... any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try
    `if WinExist("ahk_exe chrome.exe")`

Chrome and Slack show as the same control, the executable is different (checked with AutoHotKey Window Spy).